# How to use Optionals to refactor if conditions

Tags: java, java-8, refactoring

I have a method, where it checks for null and if it's null, calling a method which returns void, to assign value to the variable and returning. I cannot change method's return type as it's used in many places to load data.

Here is the example code:

```
//Global variable of class 

public List<String> listValues; 
        
public List<String> getAllValues() {
   if (listValues == null) {
       loadListValues();
   }
   return listValues;
}
        
public void loadListValues() {
   listValues = Arrays.asList("STR1","STR2","STR3");
}
```

How can I refactor to use Optionals in Java?

Comment: You shouldn't use `Optional` for this. The code as shown is sufficient, and better than abusing `Optional` would get you (in terms of memory, CPU, and readability).

Comment: Thank you..Any other way  to refactor it?

Comment: Optionals wont exactly make your code more readable/concise. ie `if (!listValues.isPresent()) {  //do something when null } var unwrappedValue = listValues.get();` because you have to do a check if there are values present, and when you want to use the values, you have to get it, though there are methods `.ifPresent() and .orElse()`

Comment: If `loadListValues` isn't just a dummy implementation: assign it directly to the field and get rid of the conditional entirely.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel In some cases, we dont have to reload the data if we directly call the method without checking null. But Thank you and appreciate the time and effort for this.